# Django rest - rearrange the nested structure

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Does django-rest framework support rearrange of models structure? I'm using the following set of models:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    posts = models.ForeignKey(
        "posts.PostsSnapshot",
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )

class PostsSnapshot(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Post(models.Model):
    snapshot = models.ForeignKey(PostsSnapshot, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='posts')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    content = models.TextField()
```

And I'm relying on ModelSerializer to provide REST access to this data:

```
class BlogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    posts = PostsSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Blog
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 2


class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'content']


class PostsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    posts = PostsSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = PostsSnapshot
        fields = ['created_at', 'posts']
        depth = 2
```

And due to that, I've got "too" nested JSON response:

```
   "posts": {
            "created_at": "2021-06-13T11:53:29.345951Z",
            "posts": [
                   ...
            ]
```

Is it possible to move the nested post data one level up? I'd like to replace the PostsSnapshotSerializer data with PostsSerializer data (but they have to be limited to this single snapshot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have a different/custom representation of your data than you have to override `to_representation()`. `depth` always provides nested data of your current object-data. `Meta` doesn´t have a feature to level `Post` and `PostsSnapshot` at your `Blog`-representation.

[Here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#custom-relational-fields) you can find an example.

#### Example

```
class PostsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    posts = PostsSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = PostsSnapshot
        fields = ['created_at', 'posts']

    def to_representation(self, data)
       # make your custom representation
       data['key'] = custom_values
       return data
```